# How to use macos key shortcuts in a linux virtualbox?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, keyboard-shortcuts, kali-linux

With macOS as host, I want cmd + c to copy in the kali linux environment instead of having to press ctrl + c instead. And this is not all, in fact, I want all macOS key shortcuts done in the terminal ex: cmd + k to clear the terminal to work as well. What happens is whenever I press cmd + c in virtualbox, I get this stupid notification

[image: vbox-cmd-c]

I tried modifying the keyboard layout based on suggestions found on the topic elsewhere, and it doesn't work. Here's the keyboard menu from which I selected macbook pro

[image: keyboard-layouts]

Comment: I use Kali (and other machines) in a VM. Kali is not Mac, so it uses Ctrl-C to copy text.

Comment: You either need a VM app that can translate on the fly, like Parallels [VBox is the lowest of the low for speed & useful additional functionality, I'm afraid], or you have to give the VM the key commands the VM OS requires.

Comment: @John Yeah I got that already, if it's not possible then what's this keyboard layout list is for?

Comment: It maps which keys exist on the physical keyboard. You have to tell it precisely, because it doesn't have smart recognition like the Mac does. [I did say VBox is the dumbest VM ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Any vm app suggestions? I'll gladly switch from virtualbox, I don't like it at all

Comment: Parallels is costly, though really the best, but you can get a personal edition of VMWare Fusion, which is nearly as good, for free.

Comment: Try a trial version of VMware Fusion - I use VMware Workstation. Try also with an Ubuntu VM to see if it responds better than Kali.

Comment: I actually don't know if VMWare can do this on the fly. I've only ever used Parallels in the past decade or more. @John - Fusion is totally free for home use. [It's the Mac equivalent of Workstation on Win, there's no Player equivalent on Mac]

Comment: This is what Parallels offers, per VM. Pic is Win, I don't have a nix VM set up, but there's a similar, if shorter, list - https://i.stack.imgur.com/uczD1.png

Comment: I'll try parallels and vmware then and I'll go with whichever works

Answer (score 1):

On the Mac: I use UTM not parallels or VMware which is free to download from their site directly or pay via mac app store.

The message you encountered was related to your virtual box preferences and not your Kali prefs. To fix it change your virtual box prefs. Use UTM.

Likewise you can assign your mac key shortcuts in Kali. IMPORTANT: you need to select your language and keyboard layout correctly first. So example "country" then under keyboard settings layout choose macbook "intl" if you are not in the US.

Once done inside your terminal you can customise what keys do what in your prefs of the terminal.

Comment: Can you give stepwise instructions.?