# How to reconfigure copy and paste keyboard shortcuts in kali linux?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vmware, kali-linux

After completely failing to reconfigure kali vm keyboard layout to match the host's (macOS) which I explained in an earlier [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1735000/how-to-use-macos-key-shortcuts-in-a-linux-virtualbox). So far, I tried installing the vm in virtualbox, vmware, and parallels and neither makes it possible. So I decided to manually reconfigure keyboard shortcuts in every application I use. However, I'm unable to change the copy and paste system wide to be `cmd + C`, `cmd + V` instead of `ctrl + C`, `ctrl + V`, because they are not present in the system settings > keyboard shortcuts. Any idea about their location or how I can reconfigure the copy and paste shortcuts globally? I'm currently using vmware fusion.